# Robot Framework - Connecting to new shell and executing commands

Tags: robotframework

I am using SSHLibrary to Open Connection and Log In to a machine which doesn't use the standard Linux Shell. After having logged in to that machine, to use the Linux shell I run the command shell and then provide a username and password to connect to it, using SSHLibrary's Write.

So far so good, but then how can I continue writing to the shell I just opened? Continuing to use Write Commands to execute something like *ls* doesn't seem to work.

The Keyword ***Connect to SDWAN Shell*** is the one I used to connect to the new shell. The new shell opens by Writing the credentials but the next Write which is the *ls* command doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Please share your RF code.

Comment: @pavelsaman I edited my question with the keyword I use.